# MongoDB collection find method doesn't work not in order

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get some db collection depends on users ID.

```
const chat = await Chat.findOne({ users });
```

now this will work : `"users": ["630200a45d22133dbe5bec44", "630200975d22133dbe5bec41"]`

but this will not work: `"users": [630200975d22133dbe5bec41", "630200a45d22133dbe5bec44"]`

Same id's, just not in the right order.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an exact match, so order matters. It seems what you want to be doing is to use [$all](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lh7HbDYVcPH), this checks all that the elements present in the input array exists in the db.

Additional you'll want to add a size check if you want to limit it so an exact match, otherwise documents like `{"users": ["630200a45d22133dbe5bec44", "630200975d22133dbe5bec41", "otherid"] }` will be matched.

Overall like so:

```
const chat = await Chat.findOne({
  users: {
    $all: [
      "630200975d22133dbe5bec41",
      "630200a45d22133dbe5bec44"
    ]
  },
  "users.2": {
    $exists: false
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lh7HbDYVcPH)

Or dynamically based on input size:

```
const input = [
      "630200975d22133dbe5bec41",
      "630200a45d22133dbe5bec44"
    ];

const sizeKey = `users.${input.length}`

const chat = await Chat.findOne({
  users: {
    $all: input
  },
  [sizeKey]: {
    $exists: false
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you Tom! but I couldn't understand 'users.2' field.

Comment: This makes sure the `users` array does not contain more ids, like the edge case i added where there is a 3rd additional id that's not in the input (both in the question and in the playground demo). if you don't need it you can remove it.

Comment: I added the syntax on how to make it dynamic based on size.